# Mocking the AuthComponent in a Component Unit Test with Cakephp

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit

I have figured out how to mock the Auth Component when testing my controllers, but am struggling to mock the Auth Component when testing my components. I am using cakephp2.0 and phpUnit.

When I use the ::generate() I am getting Error: Call to undefined method TestCalendarController::generate.

Is there a way to mock the Auth Component user() function? Or do I need to rewrite the component to avoid using it?

Thanks!

CalendarComponentTest

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeRequest', 'Network');
App::uses('CakeResponse', 'Network');
App::uses('ComponentCollection', 'Controller');
App::uses('CalendarComponent', 'Controller/Component');
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class TestCalendarController extends Controller {

}

class CalendarComponentTest extends CakeTestCase {
    public $CalendarComponent = null;
    public $Controller = null;

public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        // Setup our component and fake test controller
        $Collection = new ComponentCollection();
        $this->CalendarComponent = new CalendarComponent($Collection);
        $CakeRequest = new CakeRequest();
        $CakeResponse = new CakeResponse();
        $this->Controller = new TestCalendarController($CakeRequest, $CakeResponse);
        $this->CalendarComponent->startup($this->Controller);
}

//Here I am trying to mock the Auth component. I've tried a number of different things, and I'm not getting anything to work.
public function testAdjust() {
    $TestCalendar = $this->Controller->generate('TestCalendar', array(
        'components' => array(
            'Auth' => array('user')
        )
    ));
    $TestCalendar->Auth->staticExpects($this->any())
        ->method('user')
        ->will($this->returnValue(array('id'=>1, 'timezone'=>'America/Los_Angeles', 'type'=>'student')));

    // Test our adjust method with different parameter settings
    $this->CalendarComponent->calculate_parameters();



}

 public function tearDown() {
      parent::tearDown();
      // Clean up after we're done
      unset($this->CalendarComponent);
      unset($this->Controller);
  }


}
```

Comment: I'm interested in the solution for the controller - can you give a short example or link for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue and found a possible solution, at least it works for me.

To get some hints, I pointed my attention to the test cases for cakephp itself and in particular the one for the AuthComponent https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Test/Case/Controller/Component/AuthComponentTest.php

It seems to contain mocking of other components, for example:

```
$this->Auth->Session = $this->getMock('SessionComponent', array('renew'), array(), '', false);
```

In your case you should use something like:

```
$this->CalendarComponent->Auth = $this->getMock('Auth', array('user'));
$this->CalendarComponent->Auth->expects($this->any())->method('user')->with('id')->will($this->returnValue($user_id));
```